# Error after copy/pasting my code into a new project

Tags: android, eclipse, project

So... I'm developing an app and I had to change my project in order to add the Google API (and I wanted to change the name of the project too). 
I copied/pasted the code into a new project and even though Eclipse isn't showing any error, I'm getting one in the logCat.

```
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{eu.nigsia.christianismissues/eu.nigsia.christianismsissues.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "eu.nigsia.christianismsissues.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/eu.nigsia.christianismissues-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/eu.nigsia.christianismissues-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "eu.nigsia.christianismsissues.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/eu.nigsia.christianismissues-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/eu.nigsia.christianismissues-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
12-28 23:10:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(1259):     ... 11 more
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: There is a missing/mismatch of  class. Check your manifest.xml to ensure the links are well configured.

Comment: Thanks ¬¬. I feel so derp.